# Потоки и семафоры в Java

Tags: java, многопоточность, процесс, семафоры

Такой вопрос, если у меня есть задание:
В потоке **А** формируется общий ресурс (формирует файл), а в потоке **В** обработать его (отсортировать числа в этом файле). , сделать это нужно через семафор. То есть, мне нужно создать два класса: поток **А** и поток **В** в каждом из них реализовать метод **Run**?? Если да, то какая связь будет между этими классами и общим ресурсом? Сам реализовал класс **FileWork**(общий ресурс) который создает двоичный файл и записывает в него массив байтов.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.util.Random;

public class FileWork {
    private String filename;
    private int elementsCount;


    public String getFilename() {
        return filename;
    }

    public void setFilename(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public int getElementsCount() {
        return elementsCount;
    }

    public void setElementsCount(int elementsCount) {
        this.elementsCount = elementsCount;
    }

    public FileWork(String filename, int elementsCount) {
        super();
        this.filename = filename;
        this.elementsCount = elementsCount;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    public RandomAccessFile fileWork(String filename, int count) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(new File(filename), "rw");
        byte[] b = new byte[count];
        System.out.println("Enter byte array in file: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            b[i] = Byte.parseByte(br.readLine());
        }
        file.write(b, 0, b.length);
        return file;


    }

}
```

Comment: через семафор или монитор?

Comment: именно через семафор